# How do I make Perl's Clipboard module write utf-8 correctly to the clipboard?

Tags: perl, utf-8

Running this script (OSX 10.14):

```
use utf8;
use Clipboard;

$mystring = "Willkommen, bienvenue, أهلا, שלום, welcome";

Clipboard->copy($mystring);
```

puts the following string into the clipboard:

```
Willkommen, bienvenue, ÿ£ŸáŸÑÿß, ◊©◊ú◊ï◊ù, welcome
```

What magic will make it correct?

By the way, `Clipboard->paste()` immediately after the fragment above gets my original string back correctly. As a workaround, I'm using this:

```
    open(CLIPBOARD, "|pbcopy");
    print CLIPBOARD $mystring;
    close(CLIPBOARD);
```

. . . which works perfectly but of course is clumsy and creates an extra process each time.

Comment: Does your full perl code include `use utf8;`?

Comment: And what OS are you using?

Comment: @Shawn Edited the original to answer these (with "yes" and "OSX 10.14"). It makes no difference whether the "use utf8" is there or not.

Comment: New version works fine for me with linux (Doesn't without `use utf8`). Don't have a mac to test.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, [Clipboard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Clipboard) is using [Clipboard::MacPasteboard](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/Clipboard-0.26/lib/Clipboard/MacPasteboard.pm) to perform the copy operation. The latter module uses [Mac::Pasteboard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mac::Pasteboard). This module uses the following code (see [line 167](https://metacpan.org/release/Mac-Pasteboard/source/lib/Mac/Pasteboard.pm#L167)), at least on my machine with macOS 10.15.5:

```
open my $fh, '|-', 'pbcopy' or croak "Unable to open pipe to pbcopy: $!";
print { $fh } $data;
close $fh;
```

to copy the string to the clipboard. But the filehandle `$fh` does not have an UTF-8 layer enabled. If I add:

```
binmode $fh, 'encoding(utf-8)';
```

before the `print` statement, it works fine here. Tested on macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

Since `Clipboard` is simply calling `Mac::Pasteboard` and the latter has more options for encoding the content of the clipboard, I would suggest that you try `Mac::Pasteboard` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Followup question: It looks like the underlying code just pipes to a new pbcopy process anyway! Is this the case? I thought that with a Perl module I would avoid creating a new process for each copy. If that's not the case, I'm not sure why I'm bothering.

Comment: *"It looks like the underlying code just pipes to a new pbcopy process anyway"* : According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mac::Pasteboard) : *"macOS 10.15 Catalina appears to have broken this module. The problem appears to be in placing text on the pasteboard. As a stopgap until I can sort this out properly, the copy() method spawns pbcopy (1) if run under Darwin 19 or higher."* So I think it only calls `pbcopy` for version 10.15 or higher. Since you are using 10.14, it should not use `pbcopy`.

Comment: Awesome. Do you happen to know how to set the option I need? I tried using `$pb->set(encode=>1)` but that didn't work.

Comment: Since I am using 10.15  everything works without setting encoding for me. I can just do `$pb->copy($str);` and it works. Did you try setting encoding with `pbencode("public.utf8-plain-text");` ?

Comment: I did, and that didn't work either, nor any argument I could intuit to pbencode. Sigh. I guess I'll keep trying.